# How to calculate diff of each element in sequence in a List and then get the average in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of this class:

```
public class DailData
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public long Number { get; set; }
}
```

I need to calculate the diff each date from the previous one and them sum it and divide by total days to get the average. How can I do it with a single LINQ query?

Comment: It would be easy to do with a `foreach` if you aren't married to LINQ.  It would also be easy to document and maintain.

Comment: But I'm married to Linq:)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `Enumerable.Average`? Can we assume the `List<DailData>` is in `Date` order?

Comment: By "diff" I assume you mean difference? The date is a string. What is the format of this string?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private double calculateAvg(List<DailData> data)
    {
        var list1 = data.Take(data.Count() - 1);
        var list2 = data.Skip(1);
        var diff = list1.Zip(list2, (item1, item2) => item2.Number - item1.Number).Sum() / data.Count;
        return diff;
    }
```

Comment: Since `Zip` stops with the shortest `IEnumerable`, you can just do `data.Zip(data.Skip(1),`...

Comment: You should reconsider your marriage.  That may work, but it's pretty opaque to the reader.  It also creates and populates two additional lists.  I'm pretty sure a `foreach` solution would be simpler and clearer.

Comment: @Flydog57 It does not populate two extra lists. `Take`, `Skip`, and `Zip` will just create pass-through iterators.

Comment: Your count will be off by one with what you have (you will only have N-1 differences).  I would just do `data.Zip(data.Skip(1), (item1, item2) => item2.Number - item1.Number).Average()`

Comment: @DStanley: Thanks, good to know!  I still think I'd go with a simple `foreach` solution

Answer (score 0):

Since we know the source is a `List<T>` that is indexable, use a LINQ `for` loop emulation:

```
var ans = Enumerable.Range(1, data.Count-1).Select(n => data[n].Number-data[n-1].Number).Average();
```

Alternatively, using (one of) extension methods for scanning by pairs (scan is an APL operator like `Aggregate` but returns the intermediate values):

```
// TRes combineFn(T prevValue, T curValue)
public static IEnumerable<TRes> ScanByPairs<T, TRes>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, TRes> combineFn) {
    using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator())
        if (srce.MoveNext()) {
            var prev = srce.Current;

            while (srce.MoveNext())
                yield return combineFn(prev, prev = srce.Current);
        }
}
```

Then you can can process the pairs easily:

```
var ans2 = data.ScanByPairs((prev,cur) => cur.Number-prev.Number).Average();
```